# iOS App Store Invalid Version Later Version Has Been Closed For New Submissions

Tags: ios, xcode, version, app-store-connect

I have app in the App Store. The latest build uploaded to the App Store Connect (and is live) is version 1.10.5 and bundle is 16.

I created a new build with the version 1.2 and bundle 17. When I try to upload the new build to App Store Connect I get an error:

`Invalid Version. The build with the version “1.10.5” can’t be imported because a later version has been closed for new build submissions.`

The new 1.2 is clearly higher than 1.10.5. Why is it not letting me upload? Why is it trying to "import" 1.10.5 which is already live?

I had the same issue when going from `1.01` to `1.1`, so I changed it to `1.10` and it worked (hence the current version is 1.10.5, when it actually should be 1.1.5). I don't doubt if I change my new version to 1.20 it will work, but I am confused why this is happening and I don't want to be adding zeros every time.

Comment: 2 is clearly less than 10.  You could create 1.20 or 1.11

Comment: @Paulw11 Okay that makes sense... But what about this: I had version 1.01 and could not upload 1.1, while 1.10 worked fine

Comment: 01 is the same 1.  If I said that something cost $000000001 how many dollars would it cost? $1. You could have used version 1.02, but you chose 1.10 so your next version must be at least 1.11

Comment: FWIW no one cares about versions numbers except you/your development team.  Just pick a numbering scheme moving forward and stick to it.  For example, at my company we use x.y.z.  Each release we increment y and set z to 0.  If we need to release minor/hot fix versions before we are ready with the new 'y' version, we increment z, so we might release 1.4.0 with 1.4.1 being a fix and then 1.5.0 when it is ready

Comment: @Paulw11 Understood, thanks. My logic was mathematical: 1.2 > 1.10 and 1.1 > 1.01 > 1.0. In your analogy with cost: something will cost $1.000000001 which is lower than $1.1

Comment: @Paulw11 Yep, I agree. I was treating version as math numbers (1.1 > 1.01), and not just pure digits (1.1 = 1.01), but now I know my approach was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Apple evaluates the version number, it considers each part of the version number (separated by .) as an individual value.  Values must be greater or equal to the previous version, moving left to right, and at least one of the numbers must be greater than the previous value in that position.  Values to the right of the incremented value do not matter.

If we call the positions, moving left to right *major*, *minor* and *patch* we can examine what happened with your app:

You released 1.01, which has *major=1*, *minor=01=1* and no patch (That you have provided in your question, anyway).

You then tried to released 1.1, which has *major=1*, *minor=1* and no patch ie. It is the same version because leading zeros don't matter.  01 = 1

At this point you could have released 1.02 (*minor = 2*) but you went with 1.10.5, so *minor=10* and *patch=5*

When you then try to upload 1.2 you have *minor=2* which is less than the previous value in that position, 10.

Your next version can be 1.11.x as 11 > 10.  You do not need to jump all the way to 20.